# How do I get an empty project to compile as a dll?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I created a new VS "empty" project, and in it made a class. I decided to try this out as a library, went into properties and set the output type to class library. It compiles to a dll, though when I add it as a reference to another project, typing in "using ..." doesn't have my new library in there. If I create a new library project, past my class in there, compile that into a dll, then it works fine. So what I want to know is, what settings to I need to change in a blank project to get it to act as a dll?

Comment: You should also make sure the class is `public`.

Comment: @CodeInChaos You got this one right on the head, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`using` directives are about *namespaces*, not *assemblies*.

If your library is empty, it's not contributing anything to a namespace, so a using directive won't find anything.

It's very important that you understand the difference between a namespace and an assembly - you could have library `Foo.dll` which only contains `Bar.Xyz`. You would add a *reference* in your project to `Foo.dll`, but a using directive for `Bar`.

As a more concrete example, the `Enumerable` class in the `System.Linq` namespace comes from `System.Core.dll` - but you still add the `using` directive for `System.Linq`, not `System.Core`. Indeed, if you try to add a `using` directive for `System.Core`, you'll get an error - because that namespace doesn't exist. (A namespace effectively doesn't exist if it has no members.)

Comment: I do sort of understand the difference between namespace and assembly (probably not as well as I should, but I do). But you were right, I wasn't contributing anything to the namespace, in the silliest way: my class wasn't public. When I would paste it into the library project, the class declaration was, by default, public. The smarter we become, the dumber we become, eh? But thank you for the lesson, that does clarify some things for me.

Comment: @cost: I'm not sure what you mean by "the class declaration was, by default, public" - top-level classes are internal by default.

Comment: What I mean is, if I create an empty project, then Add -> new class, as I did when I first started programming this, it just creates "class Class1." But if I create a new library project, it creates "public class Class1." I completely glanced over the fact that it hadn't given me a public automatically